# Flutter text align center and justify at the same time

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: this is the desired output]hey i'm using rich text in flutter and i want to align it center and justify. this is beacuse i wanted the title to appear at the center while the rest of the paragraph to be justified.

```
textAlign: TextAlign.center,
textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
```

Comment: Paste the entire code which you have tried, and the output you have got and expected output picture.

Comment: i didn't try anything. in Text widget you only align your text as justify or center. but i wanted to know if there is a way

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/68859809/13431819

Comment: it threw an error.  `The following assertion was thrown building LayoutBuilder:
'package:flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart': Failed assertion: line 103 pos 12: 'dimensions !=
null': is not true.`

Comment: that is what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I can make some tweeks for the same if it is what you need.

Comment: if u could help me, i would appreciate it

Comment: Please be clear about the design , it's too vague

Answer (score 0):

```
RichText(
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  text: TextSpan(
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black),
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(
        text: 'Title\n',
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      TextSpan(
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ' +
              'Maecenas fermentum ultrices sapien, vel pharetra velit tincidunt et. ' +
              'Sed eu augue vel urna posuere laoreet at at arcu. ' +
              'Suspendisse eget lorem eget lectus sodales luctus.',
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: this doesn't justify it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any usecase of `RichText` here based on the image shown.

You can use `Column` with three children `Text` widget and apply different `textStyles` according to your needs.

Something like the following:

```
Column( children:[

Text(chapterName, 
     style:TextStyle(fontFamily:<YourFamily>,
           fontWeight:FontWeight.bold);

Text(verse,
     style:TextStyle(fontFamily:<YourFamily>,
           fontWeight:FontWeight.w500);

Text(pargraph, 
     style:TextStyle(fontFamily:<YourFamily>,
           fontWeight:FontWeight.w300);

]);
```

Comment: what i wanted to acheive is to build a book like app. so the book has chapters and i want to center those chapters. but the rest of the paragraph should be justified

Comment: @mohammedBekele i asked you couple of times in comments and you were not sure about the design , please let us know the desired output in the png form so that we could help. This description is too vague

Comment: i added the image now